# How do i add UWP to xamarin forms in VS2019?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, visual-studio-2019

I try to create a new project(xamarin form) in vs2019, and discovered that the UWP template is missing.

I created the project in vs2017 yet it did not work. now I have added a UWP project to the xamarin form app created using vs2019, how do I link them, how do I connect(refrence)  the UWP to the portable library?

I want to make use of the portable library in xamarin forms that ha UWP in it, like vs2017 versions

Comment: i never try but i think you need to convert portable class library to .net standard

Comment: but that will make me code different UI interface for the diffrent platforms. more still, the vs 2019 does not give such an option(maybe I have not seen it yet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2019 + Xamarin.Forms = UWP/EXE dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488215/vs2019-xamarin-forms-uwp-exe-dropped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS 2019 version 16.0.0 UWP head project have been removed from the Xamarin.Forms app template. However, if you install latest version of VS 2019 (16.0.1) that option should be available to you. According to the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-version-1601):

> Add option for Windows (UWP) platform when creating new Xamarin.Forms project from 'Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)' project template.

Other then that you could just simply add UWP as a separate project and set it up for Xamarin.Forms.